# Can't get full screen with ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, oracle, fullscreen

My host system is Windows.
So I open the Oracle VM and start the Ubuntu, but it appears only as a small square in the center of the application window. This happened out of no where, after I've been working with it full screen for the past two months.

When I try to insert guest editions cd image (under "Devices"), I get a message saying "Unable to insert the virtual optical disk: **C:\Program Files..** into the machine **Ubuntu**".

In the ubuntu main screen I have an icon of cd. If I right-click it and choose the "eject" option, I'm then able to insert guest editions cd image. It then asks me for password and appears to be installing something in the terminal for a couple of minutes. At the end, it tells me that they'll be available only after restarting the computer. But even after restarting the machine it steal appears only in that same small square.

Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What host OS are you using? I’m assuming it’s Windows, but it’s good to know to provide a more specific answer. Is the VM running in scaled mode? After installing the guest additions, are you able to adjust the screen resolution manually?

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll add the relevant information. The host is windows; I don't know what scaled mode is; I'm not able to adjust the screen resolution manually - it tells me the guest additions will "be available" (don't remember the exact terminology) only after restarting the machine.